# Sum Multiple Columns in Pandas DataFrame Without Losing Data Types

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame that is typically grouped on a level (or several) of the MultiIndex, then summed. This produces a DataFrame where the rows correspond to the unique values in the grouping level(s), as expected. However, for my application, I am trying to allow for there to be no grouping while maintaining the same output format (with just one row in the DataFrame), but `sum()` behaves differently with and without grouping. Specifically, if I call `sum()` on the DataFrame without grouping, it returns a Series, which conflates the data types.

### Example

If I have

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'x': [1, 2, 3, 4],
        'y': [0.0, 1.1, 5.2, 4.3]
    },
    index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
        [('A', 1), ('A', 2), ('B', 1), ('B', 2)],
        names = ('ind1', 'ind2')
    )
)
>>> df
          x    y
ind1 ind2
A    1    1  0.0
     2    2  1.1
B    1    3  5.2
     2    4  4.3
```

Then grouping on `ind1` gives me the expected

```
>>> df.groupby(level='ind1')[['x', 'y']].sum()
     x    y
ind1
A    3  1.1
B    7  9.5
```

However, without the grouping, I get a Series

```
>>> df[['x', 'y']].sum()
x    10.0
y    10.6
dtype: float64
```

The problems are that **1).** I need to continue processing the output as a DataFrame, and **2).** the sum of 'x' is now a float rather than an integer.

I am able to produce the desired results using a dummy grouping variable,

```
>>> df['dummy'] = 1
>>> df.groupby('dummy')[['x', 'y']].sum().reset_index(drop=True)
    x     y
0  10  10.6
```

But I would like to know if there is a cleaner way that is easier to understand / explain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) returns a Series, which is why you have a single dtype.

You can use [`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) passing a **list** to force a DataFrame output:

```
df.agg(['sum'])
```

Output:

```
      x     y
sum  10  10.6
```

A simpler version of the dummy grouper would be:

```
df.groupby([0]*len(df)).sum()
```

Output:

```
    x     y
0  10  10.6
```